# Run Angular 17 app in subdirectory is broken

Tags: angular, angular-router

We just upgraded from Angular v16 to v17 and now the app can not run in a subdirectory anymore.

The URL of the app is https://testserver/myApp.

However, after opening the app, the app tries to redirect to https://testserver/

The index.html defines the base URL:

```
<base href="./"/>
```

The routing definition is quite simple and has not changed:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/login/login-page.module').then(m => m.LoginPageModule)
    }
];
```

Any hints what we may have missed during the upgrade?

P.S.: The console just says: `Error: NG04002` without any further hint.